# check if values are within intervals in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large **DataFrame A** with intervals like this:

```
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 23), (1, 6), (2, 55), (3, 1), (4, 12), (5, 51),
], ("id", "x"))
# +---+---+
# | id|  x|
# +---+---+
# |  0| 23|
# |  1|  6|
# |  2| 55|
# |  3|  1|
# |  4| 12|
# |  5| 51|
# +---+---+
```

and I have a **Dataframe B** with sorted non-overlapping closed intervals like this:

```
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 5), (1, 8, 10), (2, 15, 16), (3, 20, 30), (4, 50, 52),
], ("id", "start", "end"))
# +---+-----+---+
# | id|start|end|
# +---+-----+---+
# |  0|    1|  5|
# |  1|    8| 10|
# |  2|   15| 16|
# |  3|   20| 30|
# |  4|   50| 52|
# +---+-----+---+
```

I want to check if Values of DataFrame A are contained in one of the intervals of DataFrame B and if so, save the id in a new column (`interval_id`). My **Output-DataFrame** should look like this:

```
id   x          interval_id
0    23         3
1    6          null
2    55         null
3    1          0
4    12         null
5    51         4
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently without udfs?

Comment: What are the actual sizes of your Dataframe A and B, what are the max and min and number of distinct values. You can get them by performing `df_a.agg(F.count('id'), F.countDistinct('x'), F.max('x'), F.min('x')).show(truncate=False)` and `df_b.agg(F.count('id'), F.countDistinct('start', 'end'), F.min('start'), F.max('end'), F.sum(F.col('end') - F.col('start'))).show(truncate=False)`, with using import `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`. Then you can add the results to your question.

Comment: @VincentDoba In my Dateframe I have actually timestamps from a range of 4 years. I just broke it down into small integers to make the question more generic. DF A has around 1 million rows, DF B has around 100k rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `left_join` should do the job:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df_a.join(
    df_b.withColumnRenamed("id", "interval_id"),
    F.col("x").between(F.col("start"), F.col("end")),
    "left"
).drop("start", "end")

result.show()

#+---+---+-----------+
#| id|  x|interval_id|
#+---+---+-----------+
#|  0| 23|          3|
#|  1|  6|       null|
#|  2| 55|       null|
#|  3|  1|          0|
#|  4| 12|       null|
#|  5| 51|          4|
#+---+---+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` `df_a` and `df_b` such that `df_a["x"] between df_b["start"] and df_b["end"]`.

```py
df_a = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 23), (1, 6), (2, 55), (3, 1), (4, 12), (5, 51),
], ("id", "x"))

df_b = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 5), (1, 8, 10), (2, 15, 16), (3, 20, 30), (4, 50, 52),
], ("id", "start", "end"))


df_a.join(df_b, df_a["x"].between(df_b["start"], df_b["end"]), how="left")\
    .select(df_a["id"], df_a["x"], df_b["id"].alias("interval_id")).show()
```

### Output

```
+---+---+-----------+
| id|  x|interval_id|
+---+---+-----------+
|  0| 23|          3|
|  1|  6|       null|
|  2| 55|       null|
|  3|  1|          0|
|  4| 12|       null|
|  5| 51|          4|
+---+---+-----------+
```